# How in openpyxl search for specific value in column and read the value from another column at the same row

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am Python beginner and cannot get how I can search for the specific column value in excel sheet and retrieve the value from the another column at the same row and write the value in the third column.
Example:
In column 'A' I have string number (for example employee number) and in column 'B' I have the salary.
I need to find employee with number '555', check his salary if equal to 1000 EUR and write in column 'C' adjustment value (100 EUR).
Can anybody help?

I did following:

```py
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Invoice Matrix .xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Invoicing')
for column_data in sheet['I']:
    if str(column_data.value) == emp_number:
    print(column_data.value)
```

Here I staked, because I need to check/print data from colum 'AN' and I am getting 'False'

Comment: Then do it right in Excel.

Comment: No, this only part of the script. The value that I am searching in Excel I am taking from PDF and saving in a variable . This part is working. I want to write automatic script in python. Also adjustment value I am saving in variable.

Comment: What is the specific difficulty, or do you want someone else to do it for you?

Comment: wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Invoice Matrix .xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Invoicing')  for column_data in sheet['I']:
    if str(column_data.value)==emp_number:
         print (column_data.value) Here I staked, because I need to check/print data from colum 'AN'  and I am getting 'False'

Comment: Please paste the code in the question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Your code searches for the employee id '555' and presumably finds it. At that point 
where you have `print(column_data.value)`, `column_data.row` is the row the other cells you want are on. So if `column AN` has the current salary then `sheet[f"AN{column_data.row}"].value` should return the salary then use the same method for the column where the adjustment is to go.

Comment: moken
Thank you! This is exactly what i am looking for and can go forward!

Comment: moken ! What doesn't mean - sheet[f"AN{column_data.row}"].value. What is meaning f?

Comment: The `f` denotes an `f-string`. This is something supported by Python since v3.6, Basically it's a better way to include variables in a string. Any string that is prefixed by an `f` is an `f-string` like the `r` denotes a raw string. An `f-string` allows any variable accessible to the string to be used in the string by placing it in curly brackets `{ }`. So in the example `column_data.row` is a variable denoting a row number so  `f"AN{column_data.row}"` will create a cell coordinate for column `AN` and the row value like `'AN10'`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried reading the openpyxl documentation or look into tutorials ?

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/Invoice Matrix .xlsx')
sh=wb["Invoicing"]
sh['E1']='=COUNTA(A:A)'
rowCount=int(sh['E1'].value)
for i in range(1,rowCount+1):
 if sh[f'A{i}'].value=='555' and sh[f'B{i}']=='1000EUR':
  sh[f'C{i}'].value='100EUR'
wb.save('C:/Users/Invoice Matrix .xlsx')
wb.close()
```

Comment: oh my bad , didnt notice that,now i have edited my answer with the corrections